# AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.RequestConfiguration$Builder

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

Test Ads are working fine in editor, but not on android device (test ads) using Admob V8.2.0.
That's the error massage I'm getting through appmatrica

```
Message: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.RequestConfiguration$Builder
Exception: java.lang.Throwable: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.RequestConfiguration$Builder
java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$300(Unknown Source:0)
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:83)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.RequestConfiguration$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.tts.puzzles2048.no.wifi.games-mUQ2u2b57-i91bk-o1I9WA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tts.puzzles2048.no.wifi.games-mUQ2u2b57-i91bk-o1I9WA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.tts.puzzles2048.no.wifi.games-mUQ2u2b57-i91bk-o1I9WA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 8 more
UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.FindClass (System.String name) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._AndroidJavaObject (System.String className, System.Object[] args) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
GoogleMobileAds.Android.RequestConfigurationClient.BuildRequestConfiguration (GoogleMobileAds.Api.RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
GoogleMobileAds.Android.MobileAdsClient.SetRequestConfiguration (GoogleMobileAds.Api.RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
Ads.Providers.AdMobProvider.Initialize (System.Boolean isTest, System.Boolean consent, System.String apiKey, System.String appOpen, System.String banner, System.String interstitial, System.String rewarded, System.String rewardedInterstitial, System.String mrec) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
Ads.AdsController+<InitializeCoroutine>d__108.MoveNext () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)

    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
Reported at:
```